# NODE.JS using audioconcat , configured ffmpeg but still have prob

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

**Want to concatenate two audio files. i used an npm package known as audioconcat but when i installed and configured the below code i am confronted with the following error**

```
Error: Error: Cannot find ffmpeg
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:136:22
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:123:9
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:356:16
    at nextTask (E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5057:29)
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5064:13
    at apply (E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:840:16
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:116:11
    at E:\VoiceMan\registercheck\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\utils.js:223:16
ffmpeg stderr: undefined
```

Then I put my problem on stackoverflow. A kind developer suggest me to install ffmpeg also. which i successfully installed and set there path variables but now i am having another issue which tells me that no such file are directry found..i placed my audio files in the same folder of this module. 
here is the error

```
working11
working1123423423423
ffmpeg process started: ffmpeg -i concat:audio/a(1).m4a|audio/a(2).m4a|audio/a(3).m4a -y -acodec copy all.m4a
Error: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: concat:audio/a(1).m4a|audio/a(2).m4a|audio/a(3).m4a: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\audio\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:182:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
ffmpeg stderr: ffmpeg version N-90173-gfa0c9d69d3 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libas
s --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --ena
ble-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack -
-enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidst
ab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-cuda
 --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56.  7.101 / 56.  7.101
  libavcodec     58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
concat:audio/a(1).m4a|audio/a(2).m4a|audio/a(3).m4a: No such file or directory
```

here is my code :

```
var audioconcat = require('audioconcat')


var songs = [
  'a(1).mp3',
  'a(2).mp3',
  'a(3).mp3'
]
 console.log("working11")
audioconcat(songs)

  .concat('all.mp3') 
  .on('start', function (command) {
    console.log('ffmpeg process started:', command)
  })
  .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.error('Error:', err)
    console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr)
  })
  .on('end', function (output) {
    console.error('Audio created in:', output)
  })
   console.log("working1123423423423")
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have given doesn't have any problems so it should work (It worked for me). However, logs you have provided shows that you're trying to merge .m4a files under the `audio` folder and FFmpeg can't find specified files.

`Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: concat:audio/a(1).m4a|audio/a(2).m4a|audio/a(3).m4a: No such file or directory`

Either put your ffmpeg executable in your project folder (assuming that your `audio` folder is also in your project folder) or give full path of `.m4a` files.

Like this:

```
var songs = [
  'C:\\Projects\\audio\\a(1).m4a',
  'C:\\Projects\\audio\\a(2).m4a',
  'C:\\Projects\\audio\\a(3).m4a'
];
```

Comment: thankyou for your kind suggestion. this thing helps me. but i have another problem now. how can i change the file path of merged file All.mp3

Comment: If you're reading these files' path from database, you might split one of these paths by '\' and get the folder path or you can use "__dirname" to get project folder's path and prepend this path to 'All.mp3'.

Answer (score 0):

problem was in filenames.there were space in file name.file name was like "a (1).mp3" in directory and i wrote it like "a(1).mp3" in my program.